# Trigger a Step Function in different region

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns, aws-step-functions

Is there any way to trigger a step function in one region from a step function in another region ?
I tried using a lambda in the step function to call the step function in the other region but I believe this is not supported currently.

If this is not possible, is there any AWS service that I can use to make this happen ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? How were you triggering the stepfunction. Some code would be helpful.

Comment: "I tried using a lambda in the step function to call the step function in the other region but I believe this is not supported currently. " - why is this not supported? Can you show the doc where its written this is not supported.

Also another idea is to have SNS/SQS in region - B. 
Send event from step function in region A to SNS/SQS which will trigger lambda which will trigger the step function.

Comment: You can use event bridge, SQS or API Gateway to start the execution of another step function.

Comment: 2021 and look like still not possible to invoke that cross region

Answer (score 0):

Directly invoke cross region stepfn from a step function is not possible. But I think you can write a lambda like this

```
async function executeStepFN(region, arn) {
  const sfn = new AWS.StepFunctions({
    region
  });
  await sfn.startExecution({
    stateMachineArn: arn,
    input: {},
  }).promise();
}


// call from us-east-1
await executeStepFN('us-west-2', 'arn:aws:........')
```

with this you can invoke anything from any region.